# sinatra app as a service stops working but it's service status shows as 'running'

Tags: sinatra, chef-infra, win32-service-gem

I have a sinatra app set up to run as a service using the `win32-service` gem. The app starts up fine, but it breaks after a while. According to the service status however, it's still running but I can't seem to access it from outside or on the computer itself, the only way to fix it is to stop it , delete it, re-install the service and start it up.

The app is normally self deploying (due to build pipeline, but only when I push an update), installing and running due to chef, the way its set up is that the chef server runs all it's cookbooks every 5 minutes and I think that breaks my app somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

p.s. I realise I haven't posted any code but thats only because I'm not sure what would be of any help, tell me what you need to see and I'll post it.

EDIT: Turns out it has nothing to do with chef:

Thanks to some logging I know my app was running for about 57 mins before it stopped responding to the 5 second health pings (done by varnish) and the chef run happens every 30 mins they don't co-inside, the problem is therefore chef-unrelated.

let me make it clear though, the status is still 'running' so it hasn't stopped and the logs haven't reported an error that would cause the daemon to stop running.

EDIT:

here's my daemon code:

```
  class DemoDaemon < Daemon
    def service_main
      Object.const_get("GG_Web_#{C_NAME}").run! port: PORT, server: 'thin'
      while running?
        sleep 100
        File.open(Logfile, "a"){ |f| f.puts "#{Time.now} - Service is running" }
      end
    end

    def service_stop
      File.open(Logfile, "a"){ |f| f.puts "#{Time.now} - Service stopped" }
      exit!
    end
  end

  DemoDaemon.mainloop
```

EDIT:

I've noticed the app seems to stop responding around the 50 minute mark, give or take with no logging output (I.e. exceptions, service stopped, etc) and the app status responds as `running`. 
Just in case you ask, it's 100% not chef as I disabled the chef client on the box and the app still stopped responding.

EDIT:

Also, it doesn't actually print `Service is running` or `Service stopped` to the logfile.

EDIT: 
I've narrowed it down quite a bit, what I know it's not:

1. chef
2. source code loading mechanism
3. parts of the app that does the main things, i.e. handle requests,
   load data from the database, etc (I have two apps with the same
   problem, whatever is causing has to do with whatever's the same on
   both)

I've rolled back to an earlier version of the gem that was working without this problem, and it's still doing it.

Which only leaves one thing (that I can think of), the `win32-system` gem that I'm using to create the main loop of the application and it's interaction with sinatra.

Here's the code I'm using to register the app:

```
binary_path = "#{self.rubypath} #{ROOT.gsub('/','\\')}boot_as_service.rb"
Service.create({
                       service_name: NAME,
                       service_type: Service::WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                       description: "#{DESCRIPTION}, running on: #{HOST}:#{PORT}",
                       start_type: Service::AUTO_START,
                       error_control: Service::ERROR_NORMAL,
                       binary_path_name: binary_path,
                       load_order_group: 'Network',
                       dependencies: ['W32Time', 'Schedule'],
                       display_name: NAME
                   })
```

The main application class:

```
class GG_Web_My_APP < Sinatra::Base
  set :show_exceptions, true
    set :root, ROOT + NAME
  set :server, 'thin'
  set :scss, {:style => :compact, :debug_info => false}
  Compass.add_project_configuration(File.join(settings.root, 'config', 'compass.rb'))
  Tilt.register Tilt::ERBTemplate, 'html.erb'

  enable :logging
  logging_file = File.open((Object.const_defined?('Logfile') ? Logfile : 'C:\\app.log'), "a")
  logging_file.sync = true
  use Rack::CommonLogger, logging_file

  if ENV['APPLICATION_NAME']
    set :environment, :production
    set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
  end

  get '/css/:name.css' do
    content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
    scss :"/assets/css/#{params[:name]}", Compass.sass_engine_options
  end

  helpers Sinatra::FormHelpers
  helpers Sinatra.const_get("GG_Web_#{C_NAME}")::Helpers
  register Sinatra.const_get("GG_Web_#{C_NAME}")::Api
  register Sinatra.const_get("GG_Web_#{C_NAME}")::Actions

end
```

and you've seen the code I'm using to run the app as a daemon.

I really need help to get this fixed, I'm completely out of ideas to see what could be causing this and how to fix it.

EDIT:
well, I now have confirmation of one more thing, It's not anything in my code that's causing it. It still died but the version I left running on my local machine didn't. It's something running on the server that causes it to become unresponsive.

Further edit:

Turns out that's not the problem at all, I still got nothing

EDIT:

Ok, I couldn't jut let it lie, so I went back, I managed to get my app running as a daemon without using the system32 daemon class and guess what, it still hung around till about 50 mins later (well 45 mins this time) , well since I started it without the service gem and it still hung, I'm wondering what else it could be. what could cause sinatra to hang?

Also, if I `ping localhost` it gets a reply (0% loss) but if I use curl it can't connect.

EDIT:

After systematically stripping out everything until it was just a hello world application, I can safely say it's nothing to do with my ruby code at all. By this point I'm:

1. Using rackup to start the app as a process (though I have to manually kill the main thread but the app still runs) instead of wrapping the code in a deamon and running it.
2. Turned off logging
3. Got rid of compass/sass (thought that might be hanging as less was apparantly doing that to some one elses plus I realised I wasn't using any of the features that came with it so, no point in keeping it)
4. commented out all modules and just had:

   `get '/' do
     'Hello World'
   end`

After all that it still died and by this point it was just a pure sinatra 'hello world' app; so either there's something wrong with sinatra (I doubt that as other's would have had this issue) or most probably there's something on the server that's causing it.

What's on the server that could be causing it I don't know. But at Least I'm one step closer to working that out.

Comment: How long is 'after a while', 5 minutes? What actions do your recipes take when the application is already installed (chef client log)? My guess would be your application is not responding to the service stop command correctly so you end up with an uncontrollable process sitting there.

Comment: What are you doing in your `Daemon#service_stop` and `service_main`  methods?

Comment: Also, are your stops working before your Ruby process runs into the issue?

Comment: stops? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean "service stops". When you stop the Windows service prior to your application issue, does it stop the Ruby process successfully?

Comment: Yes it stops successfully, it only doesn't stop properly when you have the services panel open on the task manager, but that's not a problem on the server.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two issues.

1. Application becoming unresponsive
2. Lack of control of the service

The two may be directly related like you suggest. The following are steps so you can separate out each concern bit by bit so you can pinpoint where the problem lies. So not an answer exactly but it might get you to an answer...

### Application becoming unresponsive

Get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653) and look at what your `ruby.exe` process is doing. Right click `ruby.exe` and select `Properties...`. 
Is it using 100% CPU? Are there any particular counters that strike you as odd?

Have a look at the `Threads` tab for the process in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653).  Are any of the TID's listed stuck at 100% of running? For each thread, in the `Stack` (bottom right hand button) if they mention `Init_ffi` they are the win32-daemon threads. `rubyeventmachine.so` are, you guessed it, eventmachine threads.

Run your app without `win32/daemon` by creating a simple app.rb or rackup file. Does the same problem occur?

Run your app with Webrick, [Puma](http://puma.io/) or Mongrel instead of Thin. Does the same problem occur?

You can poke into the stuck [process further with `gdb`](http://isotope11.com/blog/getting-a-ruby-backtrace-from-gnu-debugger) which is in the [dev kits](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) by running `msys.bat`.

```
$ gdb -p <PID>
(gdb) thread 1
(gdb) where
#0  0x62e905f9 in setproctitle () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#1  0x62e936d1 in select@20 () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#2  0x673c8524 in _SelectDataSelect (v=0x22fa38) at ../../../../ext/em.cpp:810
#3  0x62e846b8 in rb_thread_blocking_region () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#4  0x673c9307 in _Select (this=0x28d2bc8) at ../../../../ext/em.cpp:822
#5  EventMachine_t::_RunSelectOnce (this=0x28d2bc8) at ../../../../ext/em.cpp:898
#6  0x673ca6c4 in _RunOnce (this=<optimized out>) at ../../../../ext/em.cpp:503
#7  EventMachine_t::Run (this=0x28d2bc8) at ../../../../ext/em.cpp:485
#8  0x673cf4f0 in evma_run_machine () at ../../../../ext/cmain.cpp:88
#9  0x673d3297 in t_run_machine_without_threads (self=40004496) at ../../../../ext/rubymain.cpp:223
#10 0x62e7874a in rb_vm_call () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#11 0x62e6e7d8 in rb_vm_localjump_error () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#12 0x62e72eb1 in rb_vm_localjump_error () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#13 0x62e798ab in rb_iseq_eval_main () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#14 0x62d47919 in rb_check_frozen () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#15 0x62d49e50 in ruby_run_node () from c:\dply\lang\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll
#16 0x0040136f in main (argc=4, argv=0x572f80) at ../ruby_1_9/main.c:38
(gdb) thread 2 
(gdb) where...
```

Over a couple of runs you should be able to identify any threads that are stuck in the same spot (not just sleeping). If you have a thread at 100% cpu you don't have to search, just identify what the thread is doing.

### Control of the service

Your application must always be able to respond to the service requests Windows makes, no matter what it's state. If it can't respond then your service manager ends up in a state as you have experienced. This is a fairly common pitfall with managing Windows services, or any service for that matter.

- Multi threaded programs this can be achieved with a *nanny* thread
  that sits beside your normal worker threads and only deals with
  service requests. Even then you can end up with locked threads that
  won't die nicely (Java in particular).
- Single threaded programs you can have a nanny process that sits at
  the top and your (risky) work is done in children processes.

In the Ruby/MRI case it's somewhere in between the two. `win32/daemon` creates a new Ruby thread  to handle the service control requests. Note that this "thread" has no relation to the real threads we were dealing with earlier, the Ruby threads all run in the one MRI process. Ruby has the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which makes sure only one thread runs at a time in Ruby land. Threads hand off execution to each other when they can in normal operation but yours is getting stuck and never initiating the `service_stop` method. The issue is probably happening in one of the gems that runs native code threads as that's where the GIL rules are bent the most (So likely in Eventmachine, the Thin parser, `win32/daemon` or whatever other dependencies are pulled in).

Next time you attempt a service stop and it fails, you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653) to kill the `ruby.exe` service process by right clicking on the `ruby.exe` under services and `Kill Process` or use <kbd>Del</kbd>kbd> when `ruby.exe` is highlighted. You shouldn't have to recreate the service each time then.

Getting back to the *separation of concerns* idea, separating out the nanny and the worker into separate Ruby processes is one of the most sure ways of keeping the nanny simple and in control as possible. You might fix this application issue and the service problem will go away, but the next issue that locks up the process will have the same service problem.  If you seperate the nanny and worker processes, they have an operating system barrier to keep them seperate. The down side is it makes the overall system more complex on Windows as you have to deal with [spawning](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html) a child processes and signal handling between then or some form of IPC. You also need to tread carefully with stray children that are left hanging around. In this setup you would end up with a process tree like:

```
- services.exe
  - ruby.exe daemon.rb - win32/daemon
    - ruby.exe app.rb - thin/sinatra
```

So there is a possibility for the nanny to die but you still have children running around unnattended.

### Other things

Sinatra apps start Thin in threaded mode. If you run Thin directly it defaults to the evented model. Sinatra has been like this for a few years but I tend to trust Thin on Thin things. Try disabling threading:

```
set :threaded, false
```

The loop in `service_main` is unnecessary. Sinatras `App.run!` implements the loop for you, the `run!` won't return until you tell the App to `quit`.

```
 class DemoDaemon < Daemon
  def service_main
    File.open(Logfile, "a"){ |f| f.puts "#{Time.now} - Service is starting" }
    Object.const_get("GG_Web_#{C_NAME}").run! port: PORT, server: 'thin'
  end
```

You can use `App.quit!` to ask Sinatra to clean up, then maybe `exit` after a timeout.

```
  def service_stop
    File.open(Logfile, "a"){ |f| f.puts "#{Time.now} - Service stopping" }
    Object.const_get("GG_Web_#{C_NAME}").quit!
    File.open(Logfile, "a"){ |f| f.puts "#{Time.now} - Service stopped" }
  end
end
```

You can use also `rubyw.exe` for services which removes the console ($stdout/$stderr) but not important as `win32/daemon` takes care of that for you.

Comment: wow, thank you, I was about to start trying to use nssm after an attempt with powershell failed (Script worked on local but non box, turns out box uses older version and the command doesn't work). I will probably get it working with nssm to get it out the door and then use your suggestion to fix it (or at least get a better idea of where it's going wrong). The thing that bugs me the most is that it's so arbitrary, it just started out of no where and going back to before it started didn't fix it and it doesn't stop at a specific time, just around 50 mins.

Comment: one thing though, don't I need to wrap it inside of a daemon loop so it can properly stop/start and so on? EDIT: AH I see, now I get it.

Comment: nssm looks like it would do the nanny job, I'd not heard of it before. Probably better than creating your own, unless you needed to do something special to the child via Ruby. The Ctrl-C option would cover the shutdown of Sinatra/Thin then it can terminate Ruby if needed. If `win32-daemon` turns out to be the cause of the problem then your covered!

Comment: Re the problem appearing... maybe one of the gems you use was updated and that started it?

Comment: nssm was proving to be too much of a problem, any way, I tried what you suggested but I won't be able to see if it worked till tomorrow. I've checked but the main gems (sinatra and win32) that are the same between this project and another that are both having the same issue, haven't been updated within the last few weeks (when the problem appeared).

Comment: I've updated the question, any idea what could cause the app to stop responding?

Comment: Did the problem occur running without `win32-daemon`? Did the problem occur using web servers other than Thin? Did the `where` in gdb highlight anything?

Comment: The problem doesn't occur when run without win32-daemon (as in just using rackup from the command line) It still dies even after the alterations you suggested. I couldn't get GDP to work and the only server that works (that I could get working) is thin.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem doesn't occur when running without win32 daemon, try run it with task scheduler rather as a windows service.

Comment: I've looked but I don't know how to do that with chef.

Comment: You can run task scheduler cmd utilities with chef.